# How to avoid branching while using a static factory pattern?

Tags: c#, oop, refactoring, static-factory

I often get stuck in branching when deploying the static factory pattern , is there a way to make it more neat than the below code :

```
 private static TestEdition GetCurrentEdition(userconfig config)
    {
        if (config.Edition == Edition.typea)
        {
            return new TestEdition3(config);
        }
        else if (config.Edition == Edition.typeb)
        {
            return new TestEdition4(config);
        }
        return new UnsupportedEdition(config);  
    }
```

Comment: Use polymorphism?

Comment: @CaiusJard - He is using polymorphism already.

Comment: Er; no. He has a polymorphic capability, but having a huge if block that laboriosly tests and returns different sub types hard coded is not leveraging that polymorphism

Comment: FYI, this is the [static factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-factory/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use this kind of thing a lot:

```
private static Dictionary<Edition, Func<userconfig, TestEdition>> _factories =
    new Dictionary<Edition, Func<userconfig, TestEdition>>()
    {
        { Edition.typea, c => new TestEdition3(c) },
        { Edition.typeb, c => new TestEdition4(c) },
    }

private static TestEdition GetCurrentEdition(userconfig config)
{
    if (_factories.ContainsKey(config.Edition))
    {
        return _factories[config.Edition](config);
    }
    return new UnsupportedEdition(config);
}
```

The huge advantage is that you can configure and extend the `Dictionary<Edition, Func<userconfig, TestEdition>>` at run-time.